# Infintely/Finitely Occurring Event Sequence in Terms of Subevents

Tags: probability

I'm doing an undergrad probability subject and its been a while since I've done probability. In a tutorial I missed (I got the questions online, no solutions) we were given the question:

Let $B, C,$ and $D$ be (possibly overlapping) events, $\{A_n\}$ a sequence of events defined as follows:

$A_n=
\begin{cases}
B &\text{for } n=1,2,3\\
C &\text{for } n=k^2, k\geq 2\\
D &\text{for all other values of } n
\end{cases}$

Express in terms of $B, C,$ and $D$ the following events: i) $A_n$ occurs infinitely often. ii) $A_n$ occurs finitely often.

I'm really struggling to get my head around how to start the question. I've looked into the Borel-Cantelli lemmas, but I just can't relate them properly to the question. Any help would be appreciated, I really feel like this shouldn't be as difficult I'm making it.

Answer (score 2):

The Borel-Cantelli lemmas aren't needed, since you're not actually calculating any probabilities.  You need to think simpler.  The question is saying: if $B$ occurs, then $A_n$ occurs for $n = 1, 2, 3$; if $C$ occurs, then $A_n$ occurs for all square $n \ge 4$; if $D$ occurs, then $A_n$ occurs for all nonsquare $n \ge 5$.  In particular, $A_n$ occurs infinitely often iff $C$ or $D$ occurs, so event (i) is $C \cup D$. Event (ii) is the complement of this event, which is $(C \cup D)^c = C^c \cap D^c$ (that is, $A_n$ occurs finitely often iff neither $C$ nor $D$ occurs).  Note that you don't care about $B$: it only affects a finite number of $A_n$, and doesn't change whether the number of them that happen is finite or infinite.

(And welcome to math.SE!  Ask if you need more clarification.)